# Device to measure current in the range of pico Ampere (pA)

Tags: current, current-measurement, amperage

I am working on an electrochemical quantitative sensor and considering the reaction rate I can predict a current output in the order of 10-1 pA (pico Ampere). 
I was wondering if there is any device or way to measure a current of this order of magnitude with accuracy (without being too expensive).

Comment: please update your post with the accuracy required and actual cost limit

Comment: Burr Brown DDC112.

Comment: @jonk  DDC112 - typical input bias current 0.1pA, max 10pA. It's one of those infuriating devices which will typically work, but can't be guaranteed to. It uses precisely the architecture I would have dreamt up to do it in discretes.

Comment: @Neil_UK You can achieve (with work and buying dice) quite excellent results. I was able to achieve a noise floor (the Hamamatsu diode included) of about 2-6 fA with bandwidth of 10Hz. Be aware that it will "burn" at 7 uA or more (metalisation migration of a weak inner trace that I had to get from Jim, one of the designers.) I worked closely with Burr Brown at the time and was able to achieve quite good results. I did use a 3-tier cooling stack in something that looked like a TO-3 package and learned to use wire-bonding equipment in the process.

Comment: @Neil_UK I didn't have the space to add: for high currents you have to rapidly reset the device and accumulate. I used this device over a signal range of about 100fA to about 5 uA. More than 8 orders of magnitude. Which was critical to the application. I succeeded.

Comment: Keithley Electrometer if you need a ready-made DMM-like lab instrument and price is no object. Lowest range is 20pA with resolution 10aA (yes, attoamps). Price around 10k$. Pretty much anything with the Keithley name is gold standard.